# Assigning value of QLineEdit variable to a QStringList variable

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Can anyone tell me how to assign all stuff in lineEdit to a QStringList variable? Suppose I have xyz typed in a QLineEdit and I want to shift it to QstringList variable, how can i do that E.g

`QStringList abc;`

How can I take all typed stuff from lineEdit to abc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the value of the QLineEdit to QStringList:

```
abc->append(lineEdit->text());
```

Or create new QStringList with text from QLineEdit:

```
QStringList abc(lineEdit->text());
```

Answer (score 1):

The lineedit can export its content to a QString

```
QString xLineEditContent = xLineEdit.text();
```

Then you can append this string to a QStringList

```
QStringList xStringList;
xStringList << xLineEditContent;
```

It should work (you can also combine lines to avoid xLineEditContent instantiation).